# How can I calculate at which distance a moving object stops in this physics emulation?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, absolute-convergence, convergence-acceleration

There is an object which has an initial velocity of $`V_1`$ and has an acceleration of $`V^2 k+d+b`$ in the opposite direction, where `k,d,b are constants`. What will be the distance traveled until reaching the velocity of $`V_2`$?

I have tried some integration and derivation and all the time I found something useful but I stuck after some point. Are these equations right and can you help me finding the result as $V_1,k,d,b$?

[Graphs and equations I wrote for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8Fk.png)

Comment: You can, with a little practice, post here [with typeset mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the differential equation

$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = -(kV^2 +d+b) $$

$$ \frac{V'}{kV^2 + d+b} = -1 $$
$$ \frac{V'}{\frac{k}{d+b} V^2 + 1} = -d-b $$

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{k}{d+b}}$ and $\beta = \alpha(d+b) = \sqrt{k(d+b)}$.

$$ \frac{\alpha V'}{\alpha^2 V^2+1} = -\beta $$

$$ \int \frac{\alpha V'}{\alpha^2 V^2+1} dt = -\int \beta\, dt $$

$$ \arctan(\alpha V) = -\beta t + C $$

$$ V = \frac{1}{\alpha} \tan(C - \beta t) $$

At $t=0$ we must have $V=V_1$, so $\tan C = \alpha V_1$. These equations are valid for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{\arctan(\alpha V_1)}{\beta}$.

If $t_f$ is the time when $V=V_2$, then $C-\beta t_f = \arctan(\alpha V_2)$.

Then the total distance from time $t=0$ to time $t=t_f$ is

$$ X = \int_0^{t_f} V\, dt $$
$$ X = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^{t_f} \tan(C-\beta t)\, dt $$
$$ X = \frac{1}{\alpha \beta} \left[ \ln \cos(C-\beta t) \right]_{t=0}^{t=t_f} $$
$$ X = \frac{1}{k} \big[\ln(\cos \arctan(\alpha V_2)) - \ln(\cos \arctan(\alpha V_1))\big] $$

If $\theta = \arctan y$, then $y=\tan \theta$, and $1+y^2 = 1+\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta = (\cos \theta)^{-2}$, so $\cos \arctan y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$.

$$ X = \frac{1}{k} \left[ \ln \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2 V_2^2}} -\ln \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2 V_1^2}} \right] $$

$$ X = \frac{1}{2k} \ln \frac{1+\frac{k}{d+b} V_1^2}{1+\frac{k}{d+b} V_2^2} $$

$$ X = \frac{1}{2k} \ln \frac{kV_1^2 + d + b}{kV_2^2 + d + b} $$